# Uiautomator- how to get the text value on the textview obj of which the checkbox value is checked??

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to get the textview value of the linearlayaout having the checkbox with an (ischecked == true) property. Basically trying to get the text of all the items whose corresponding checkbox is checked.

```
->ListView
   -> LinearLayout
       -> Checkbox
       -> textview
       -> textview
```

I tried doing the following:

```
     UiScrollable citylistView = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector());
     listView.setMaxSearchSwipes(100);
     listView.scrollTextIntoView(name);
     listView.waitForExists(5000);
     UiObject listViewItem = listView.getChildByText(new UiSelector()
        .className(android.widget.CheckBox.ischecked(true));
     String cityName =listViewItem.gettext();
```

But this doesn't seem to work. 
I'd really appreciate if anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just adding to the answers you already have. What you are doing will only work if the developer was careful enough to set the Text of the checkbox. From the apps I've been seeing this seldom happens (the same for the "labelled by" property). In that case you have to try and access the TextView next to the checkbox with some kind of heuristic.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

- The selector on the first line will match any element. This probably isn't what you want. Also, based on the next few lines it looks like, `citylistView` should be `listView`?
- Lines 5-6 won't compile. The [UiSelector.className(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#className(java.lang.String)) method takes a String or a Class object, so it should either be `.className("android.widget.CheckBox")` or `.className(android.widget.CheckBox.class)`
- Also on line 6 you're missing a closing parenthesis before calling `isChecked(true)`. Instead of `.className(android.widget.CheckBox.ischecked(true))` it should be `.className(android.widget.CheckBox.class).ischecked(true)`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see is

```
.className(android.widget.CheckBox.ischecked(true));
```

is incorrect as that function is expected a string. I think you need to rewrite it like this.

```
UiObject checkBox = listView.getChildByText(new UiSelector()
    .className("android.widget.CheckBox");
if(checkBox.isSelected()){
   String cityName = listView.getChildByText(new UiSelector()
    .className("android.widget.TextView").gettext();
}
```

If I am correct this should help with your solution, it would be useful for a screen shot of the section and the xml, be easier to know how it is directly laid out. Unfortunately I couldn't test this solution but I hope it helps.

Comment: He has an error but not exactly that.
He should UiObject checkBox = listView.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.CheckBox").checked(true));